# Need to access HashMap in my action class from the inside of a Struts2 iterator

Tags: java, struts2

I am writing a Struts2 application working with a database which has a column which consists of either `Y` or `N`. I need to present the columns as either `Yes` or `No`. So, I have `seqIdMap` in the action class:

```
private HashMap<String, String> seqIdMap; 
public ReviewQuestionAction(){
    seqIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    seqIdMap.put("Y", " Yes ");
    seqIdMap.put("N", " No ");
}
```

I use the following Struts2 code to generate the radio labels and it works fine:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="yesOrNo" class="pull-right">
        <s:text name="yesOrNo"></s:text>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
   <s:radio name="indicatiorFlag" id="yesOrNo" list="seqIdMap"  />
</div>
```

My issue is that, I need to display the `indicatiorFlag` as `Yes` or `No` instead of `Y` or `N`, what I get from database. I tried the following as advised on few sites, but it doesn't work:

```
<s:iterator value="questionInfoList">
<s:url var="link" action="reviewQuestion" method="getQuestionInfo">
    <s:param name="seqId">
        <s:property value="seqId"/>
    </s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{link}">
    <s:property value = "seqId"/></s:a>
<s:property value = "%{seqIdMap.indicatiorFlag}"/>
```

I can display a `Y` or `N` if I replace `%{seqIdMap.indicatiorFlag}` with `indicatiorFlag`. But I haven't figured out how to use the `indicatiorFlag` to a `key` in the `seqIdMap`.  I have tried several different ways including `%{seqIdMap['indicatiorFlag']}` and

```
<s:set name="newMap" var = "seqIdMap">
```

outside the iterator and then `%{#newMap[indicatiorFlag]}` inside of it.  Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.  I realize `indicatiorFlag` should be `indicatorFlag` but I inherited the name.

Comment: Your map seqIdMap is a Map<String,String>, I don't understand why you call `indicatiorFlag` on it. You should show us the structure of `questionInfoList`

Comment: questionInfoList is a list of questionInfo objects.  The fields in the questionInfo object match the columns in the database so each object is the java representation of a record in the database.  One of the fields is the indicatiorFlag which is a String value of either "Y" or "N".  I left the rest of the code out because it is working fine.  I use the indicatiorFlag as the key to seqIdMap to retrieve either "Yes" or "No" for my display.

Comment: @ponder275: Just use `listValue` attribute of `<s:radio>` tag.

Comment: You should note however that 1) This would be better suited into an Enum, and 2) if using JPA (or Hibernate), there is an inbuilt feature that converts booleans to 'Y' / 'N'. IMHO Boolean > Enum > HashMap. My 2 cents.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Could you expand on how to use an Enum?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to know @ponder275 ? How to create an Enum in Java ? How to read it in JSP through OGNL ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I know how to use Enum's in Java.  I wasn't clear what part of my data structure would be better as an enum.  I assume it would be the Yes and No part of my hashMap, or do I completely replace the hashMap with an enum?  Help on how to read it in JSP through OGNL would be appreciated also.  Thanks!

Comment: @ponder275 Ok I'll answer expanding the comment to add value to the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got converted `Y` and `N` to `Yes` and `No` by the following code:

```
<s:iterator value="myTestList" var="mytestBean">
    <s:property value="%{seqIdMap[#mytestBean.name]}" />
</s:iterator>
```

Here, `mytestBean.name` held the values of `Y` and `N`.

Comment: I will give your solution a try.  I don't have access to my code at home so I will try it when I get back to work on Tuesday.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had tried the following code and it didn't work but after looking at James's solution I tried it and it also works.

```
<s:property value = "%{seqIdMap[indicatiorFlag]}"/>
```